# ASP.NET and HTML/XML in control text

Tags: asp.net, xml, user-input

I have a number of webforms which must be able to accept XML input (containing, of course, the `<` and `>` characters, which I believe is what is causing problems). However, presently whenever I click a submit button and one of the form fields contains this kind of input a `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException` exception with code 500 is thrown. If the input has no `<` and `>` everything goes smooth. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be cautious about turning off Page validation.  Look at HTML Encoding the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

Request validation is enabled by default. You can turn it off all pages using web.config:

```
<configuration> 
      <system.web> 
           <pages validateRequest="false" /> 
      </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

or just on that page by adding it to the directive:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: -1 That opens up a whole bucket of security problems.  The default value is true for a reason.

Comment: I agree not the best way. Just depends on how much is on the page. Should have included this from the [Asp.Net white paper](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation) :

Caution: When request validation is disabled, content can be submitted to a page; it is the responsibility of the page developer to ensure that content is properly encoded or processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want the page request validation to function properly (i.e. w/o setting it false) you can always character substitute the < & > symbols and re-substitute them back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you're dealing with HTML/XML input by a user you have to be extremely careful and make you sure you sanitize the input thoroughly.

Different web controls implement (or don't) HtmlEncoding by default.  Take a look at  [Which ASP.NET Controls Automatically Encodes?](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-08-91-89-96/asp.net_5F00_control_5F00_encoding.htm) for a detailed list.

I'd also recommend looking at the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=325).

Can you edit your question and post some of the code (and maybe sample input that causes the error)?  The `<` and `>` might be the cause, but it might be a red herring as well.